# stuck in doing xor two binary numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, xor

i'm trying to do the XOR for two binary numbers
for example :

> 10100010 xor 01000101 = 11100111

code for matlab :

```
y =  bitxor (10100010,01000101 )
```

but when i use this ,
 the matlab sees these 2 numbers as a decimal numbers and it gives a decimal answer

> = 9789327

how can i xor two binary numbers and have a binary answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be that MATLAB is expecting the input in double representation:

Not the most elegant, but one method:

```
y = dec2bin(bitxor(bin2dec(num2str(10100010)), bin2dec(num2str(01000101))));
```

Or, representing the bits as elements in an vector:

```
y =  bitxor([1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0],[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]);
```

Comment: Well, MATLAB is expecting an input that it knows how to handle, and it doesn't have binary representation as part of its language.  Also, why use `num2str` when a `char` literal will work just as well?

Comment: I had used num2str because I assume the values are being read / imported into MATLAB as doubles.